# Is 1-arg overload of variadic template function useful? Should it used a magic && reference? Is Copy-Elision taking place in this case?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, copy-elision, return-by-value

I have an existing `std::ostream`-like type, which has several `operator<<` overloads for various types. Since that type is used as a `const&` argument to other APIs, I'm adding convenience *factory*-functions for easy *inline* use, at call sites.

I wrote the code below, which works fine (VS2019 and GCC9), but I was wondering several things:

1. Do I really need the 1-arg overload? Is there benefits to having it?
2. The 1-arg overload uses (Scott Meyers') magic-references, but should the variadic overload use them to? I tried `Ts...&&`, but VS2019 didn't like that.
3. In Debug, I followed the return statements, and saw osl being move-constructed, when I was expecting Copy-Elision to take place, for such a helper, to make it *zero-overhead*. Is this a Debug-build artifact? Or somehow Copy-Elision cannot take place here? If so, why?

```
template <typename T> inline
OStreamLike bind(T&& val) {
    OStreamLike osl(1);
    osl << val;
    return osl;
}

template <typename... Ts> inline
OStreamLike bind(Ts... vals) {
    OStreamLike osl(sizeof...(Ts));
    ((osl << vals), ...);
    return osl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do I really need the 1-arg overload? Is there benefits to having it?

1rst overload isn't required.

The only benefit is the reference to avoid copy (which might be done for the variadic overload).

> The 1-arg overload uses (Scott Meyers') magic-references, but should the variadic overload use them to? I tried Ts...&&

Forwarding-reference for variadic would use `Ts&&... args` syntax.

but from the above code, you don't need forwarding references, regular const reference would be my choice `const Ts&... args`.

> In Debug, I followed the return statements, and saw `osl` being move-constructed, when I was expecting Copy-Elision to take place, for such a helper, to make it zero-overhead. Is this a Debug-build artifact? Or somehow Copy-Elision cannot take place here? If so, why?

NRVO is not mandatory, even in C++17.

NRVO is applicable here, and I expect it at least in optimized build.

Comment: Based on your feedback, I removed the 1-arg overload, which made a call site, where `bind()` was used *inline* (i.e. as a temporary, like `exec(..., bind(...), ...)`), start to fail building. Somehow VS2019 could no longer resolve the `exec()` function being called... I tried all 3 forms, `Ts...`, `const Ts&...`, and `Ts&&...` to no avail. So I just put back the 1-arg overload, and switched to `Ts&&...` instead of `Ts...`

Comment: @ddevienne: No issues [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8718c2996fbb438c).

Comment: I have two `exec()` overloads. One w/ and one w/o an `const OStreamLike&` argument (i.e. w/ or w/o binds). Both are variadics themselves (they are specialized front-ends to `fmt::format`). They are like `exec(Arg1&, fmt::CStringRef format_str, Args&&... args)` w/o binds, and `exec(Arg1&, const OStreamLike&, fmt::CStringRef format_str, Args&&... args)` w/ binds. Sorry for leaving this out earlier.

Comment: I suggest to ask then another question.